# Load forms into panel

Tags: angular

An Angular application that we are developing has features like: "Add User", "Edit Project". Those features are triggered by buttons somewhere in the application and when the button is clicked, a panel should slide out with the form to add a user or edit a specific project.

I'm looking for an approach to load those forms/components into this panel without having this panel to know all the possible forms/components that it might be used for.

Those forms/components also would need to be loaded with some data like with the selected `Project` in the example of the "Edit Project" feature.

What would be the Angular way to achieve this?

Comment: See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q-HL9YX_pk and you will know.

Comment: Your "panel" can be its own component with inputs that decide wat it is used for. For the animations, you might want to read https://angular.io/guide/animations for a start on how to combine components and animations.

Comment: If you separate out your forms as components then you can use the panel's ViewContainerRef to create the form component and attach to the panel's view.

Comment: @StPaulis This did not work for me. In this video I found basic stuff about state management. My question is how to do the angular stuff. How can I show a component A and load another component B or C into it without having component A to know anything about component B or component C. To model and manipulate the state and broadcast the changes with RxJS, this is straightforward. I just don't know the Angular part.

Comment: @MikeS. What would be passed into this panel component as input? A component instance?

Comment: It depends on what you're using it for. The easiest way would be putting whatever content you want to be displayed inside of the panel in the body of the panel component. Then you can display the content inside of the template of the panel component with `<ng-content></ng-content>`. Another way that allows you to be a litle more abstract is [dynamic component loading](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)